# What's the standard way to login to a client software in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, windows

To login to a website I can use `curl`, what about when I need to login to a client software?

Comment: This way to broad. Provide some specifics. What do you have already, what have you tried?

Comment: 48 questions, 0 votes, 0 answers, 38% accept.  That's quite poor, you are going to have to start participating here if you want to keep the help coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erm... there is no 'standard way' for logging into client software in C or C++

The concept of 'logging in' does not exist in any language that I am aware of.

What you are after is some of API or library of code that will provide this functionality for you, or do it your self.

Your question imply that's you are doing some sort of logging into a web based service, such as twitter, there are libraries out there will make it fairly easy for you to send a request to a web server and get the response.

I can't remember what it actually is, but windows does provide a very good API for this sort of thing... not sure if I used C# though, but I am sure their will be a C and a C++ version.

Oh, and are you using C or C++?

Comment: No,I'm not trying to login to a web based service now,which I already managed with curl.

Comment: Seems no problem now,my problem was because I didn't realize that I can just re-use the authenticated socket until just now...

Answer (score 0):

Using the software API. Same as the websites. `curl` just implements the HTTP communication which will be replaced by function calls, message passing, or whatever else the software uses for API implementation.